# Share Azure project backlog settings with others in the team

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-boards

Is there a possibility where I can share the configuration of my boards and backlogs with the others in my team?

This way they all have the same columns and order columns that I have.

Answer (score 0):

To configure (add, remove and order) columns in the "**`Boards/Backlogs`**" page, the users do not need any additional permission, as long as the users at least have the **Reader** permission in the project.

Each user can configure the columns on the "**`Boards/Backlogs`**" page on his own side. All the changes each user does for columns can only be applied to the "**`Boards/Backlogs`**" page on his own side, and not affect on other users' sides.

So, if you want your other team members have the same columns and columns order with that of you on the "**`Boards/Backlogs`**" page, you can ask the members to add, remove and order the columns on their own side following the style on your side. For more details, you can see "[**Change column options**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/set-column-options?view=azure-devops)".

To configure the "**`Boards/Boards`**" page, you need the permissions for configuring team settings. [To configure team settings, you must be added to the **team administrator** role or be a member of the **Project Administrators** security group.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/customize-cards?view=azure-devops#prerequisites)

Only the Administrator users can configure the "**`Boards/Boards`**" page. The style configured by the Administrator users is applied to the whole team. That means all the members in your team will see the same things on the "**`Boards/Boards`**" page. So, you do not need to grant every team member the permissions to configure the "**`Boards/Boards`**" page. Just you Administrator users have the related permissions is OK.

Comment: Hi @Bright Ran-MSFT, Yeah I am aware of the Column Options, however I was wondering if there was a template settings for the Columns so that the other team mates can just select this option and not have to go and manually select the required columns

Comment: @Rakavy not without exporting your work item templates, and importing them into the other project. And even then, you'd still need to configure the boards on the project manually.